# Wordpress Plugin for Maps of specific Tweets?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, twitter, geo-data, map

Is there a Wordpress Plugin that you can give it a list of old tweets (specified by url or tweet number (for example: http://twitter.com/#!/leeand00/status/20215977534820353) and put them on a map, which will slowly move between them (in demo mode) and then allow the user to click on those tweets?

(Just figured I'd check before implementing one)

P.S. Can someone please tag this post with "Google Maps" or "Maps" please.

Comment: So are you wanting to read the location data from a tweet and place it on a map? Maybe I missed it, but I didn't notice any location data supplied on your sample tweet.

Comment: @Adam Good catch Adam!  Well I can't guarantee that the tweet will have location data attached (or the correct location data attached to it), so I think I'd rather be able to specify that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this will help in EXACTLY the way you are looking for, but when it comes to map integration into posts, I love to use [MapPress](http://wphostreviews.com/mappress). It supports a pretty robust API which allows you to hook into the plugin to do some custom things, and I'm sure with a little work you could get to where you want to be with your project. I don't usually like the pay-for plugins but I highly recommend buying his MapPress Pro, it works very very well, is highly versatile, and he is always keeping it updated.